# XML Validation Error - Pattern Constraint Failed

Tags: xml, validation

The zipcode '064843444' returns a validation error of "The value '64843444' is invalid according to its datatype 'ZipCodeType' - The Pattern constraint failed"

XML:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ZipCodeType">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Zip code pattern type.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{5})|([0-9]{9})"/>
</xs:restriction>

<xs:element name="Zip" type="ZipCodeType" minOccurs="0">
   <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Zip code. 5 or 5+4.</xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

I'm under the impression the leading zero is being truncated and then being evaluated as 8 digits as opposed to 9. Does anyone know how to correct this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an XML document that actually illustrates the problem?

Comment: I only see XSD... I'm just looking for the XML-equivalent of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), if you will. A super-simple schema and super-simple XML document that illustrates the problem. Right now all you've given is a schema fragment. 2 reasons to give more: 1) You might figure it out in the process of slimming it down. 2) Everybody here has their own coding problems and helps here in spare moments. You want us to solve it quickly or we might not solve it at all. :)